# Counting Change in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that asks the user to input their initials, followed by the amount of quarters, nickels, dimes, and pennies that they have and then the program will output those values. After that, the program will take the given amount of quarters, nickels, dimes and pennies and count them up to __ dollars and __ cents, all without using loops or arrays. Here's what I have so far

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {    //Declarations
    char firstinitial, middleinitial, lastinitial;
    int quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies;
    int dollars, cents;

    //Data/Input

    //Output
    printf("Enter your initials, first, middle and last: ");
    scanf("%c", &firstinitial);
    scanf("%c", &middleinitial);
    scanf("%c", &lastinitial);

    printf("Hello %c.%c.%c., let's see what your coins are worth.\n",
           firstinitial, middleinitial, lastinitial);

    printf("Enter number of quarters: ");
    scanf("%d", &quarters);
    printf("Enter number of dimes: ");
    scanf("%d", &dimes);
    printf("Enter number nickels: ");
    scanf("%d", &nickels);
    printf("Enter number of pennies: ");
    scanf("%d", &pennies);

    puts("");

    printf("Number of quarters is %d.\n", quarters);
    printf("Number of dimes is %d.\n", dimes);
    printf("Number of nickels is %d.\n", nickels);
    printf("Number of pennies is %d.\n", pennies);

    //Calculations
    dollars = quarters / 25;
    cents %= 25;
    dollars = dimes / 10;
    cents %= 10;
    dollars = nickels / 5;
    cents %= 5;
    pennies = dollars;
    printf("Your coins are worth %d dollars and %d cents", dollars, cents);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, asking for initials and the amount of coins all works. I just need help trying to find the right way to calculate the change because the way I tried to doesn't work. Thank you!

Comment: You fail to accumulate the dollars and cents from each denomination of coins.

Comment: Regarding:  `scanf("%c", &firstinitial);
    scanf("%c", &middleinitial);
    scanf("%c", &lastinitial);`  if the user entered 'abc' then this code will work,  However, if the user enters 'a b c'  then it will not work because the `%c` does not skip over 'white space'  at a minimum suggest: `scanf(" %c", &firstinitial);
    scanf(" %c", &middleinitial);
    scanf(" %c", &lastinitial);`  Note the leading space before each `%c`.  That space will cause the leading 'white space'  to be consumed/discarded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to initialize your variables.

```
int quarters = 0;
int dimes = 0;
int nickels = 0;
int pennies = 0;
int dollars = 0;
int cents = 0;
```

Then just add up the total number of cents. Like so:

```
//Calculations
cents += quarters * 25;
cents += dimes * 10;
cents += nickels * 5;
cents += pennies;
```

This will put the total number of `cents` into the variable `cents`. But it looks like you  need to split into dollars and cents. Do this:

```
dollars = cents/100;
cents = cents%100;

printf("Your coins are worth %d dollars and %d cents", dollars, cents);
```

This should be what you want.

Comment: You don't need the cast. The code is casting `cents` to an `int`, but `cents` was declared as in `int`, so the cast does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Yep. I like showing the cast for new learners so that they realize that the answer is float (whereas modulo is int). If there is a reason not to, then I will change the answer

Comment: @ gnodab `cents/100` is not a float. Both `cents` and `100` are integers. In C, the result of integer division is an `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Good to know